# How to make bootstrap popover move along with fixed button

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I wanted to achieve a behavior that my popover should moves along with my fixed button as I scroll the page.
I have following JS, CSS and HTML:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btn-pop").popover('show');            
});
```

```css
h1{
    color:Silver;
}
#btn-pop{
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 47%;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">

        <!--These are some contents-->
        <div class="row">            
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1>                                               
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1>                                   
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1>                                   
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1>                                   
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1>                                   
        </div>

        <!--This is main thing--> 
        <button id="btn-pop" rel="popover" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-original-title="Setting" data-content="Check this amazing feature">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>
        </button>

    </div>
```

I hope the above code make some idea that what I actually wanted to achieve. Thanks in advance.

You can see the problem:

[image: You can see the problem]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to both move together when you scroll you have to change the position of your button to `position: absolute`

> An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the
>   viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the
>   page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used
>   to position the element.

try this:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btn-pop").popover('show');
});
```

```css
h1 {
    color:Silver;
}
#btn-pop {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;  /*changed to absolute*/
    top: 47%;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <!--These are some contents-->
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <!--This is main thing-->
    <button id="btn-pop" rel="popover" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-original-title="Setting" data-content="Check this amazing feature"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>

    </button>
</div>
```

If you want both stay in same place add `position: fixed` to the popup like this:

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btn-pop").popover('show');
});
```

```css
h1 {
    color:Silver;
}
#btn-pop {
    z-index: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 47%;
    left: 0;
}
.popover {
    position: fixed !important;  /* I use !important because in this snippet bootstrap's styles overwrite mines but in general it is not nedded*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <!--These are some contents-->
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <div class="row">
         <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Itaque, optio corporis quae nulla aspernatur in alias at numquam rerum ea excepturi expedita tenetur assumenda voluptatibus eveniet incidunt dicta nostrum quod?</h1> 
    </div>
    <!--This is main thing-->
    <button id="btn-pop" rel="popover" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-original-title="Setting" data-content="Check this amazing feature"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cog"></span>

    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm glad to help you # :-)